# Sets and Indexing in GAMS

Tags: math, indexing, set, integer-programming, gams-math

I am trying to solve a mathematical optimization model. I want to define a set in my model, say, **i** and I want it to be from 0 to 15. Is it possible? Or I have to define from 1 to 16? I am using the demo version of GAMS (General Algebraic Modeling System) available on the website.

Thanks

PS: Someone with enough reputation please create a GAMS tag!

Answer (score 1):

You can define the set from 0 to 15 if you wish. For example,

```
set i 'plants' /i0*i9/
parameter a(i);
a(i)=uniformint(1,9);
display a;
```

Here are the results,

```
PARAMETER a  
i0 2.000,    i1 8.000,    i2 5.000,    i3 3.000,    i4 3.000,    i5 3.000
i6 4.000,    i7 8.000,    i8 1.000,    i9 5.000
```

Hope that helps.
Sophia